# Strange uses of movzx by Clang and GCC

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, x86, clang

I know that `movzx` can be used for dependency breaking, but I stumbled on some `movzx` uses by both Clang and GCC that I really can't see what good they are for. Here's a simple example I tried on Godbolt compiler explorer:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

int add2bytes(uint8_t* a, uint8_t* b) {
    return uint8_t(*a + *b);
}
```

with GCC 12 `-O3`:

```text
add2bytes(unsigned char*, unsigned char*):
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsi]
        add     al, BYTE PTR [rdi]
        movzx   eax, al
        ret
```

If I understand correctly, the first `movzx` here breaks dependency on previous `eax` value, but what is the second `movzx` doing? I don't think there's any dependency it can break, and it shouldn't affect the result either.

with clang 14 `-O3`, it's even more weird:

```text
add2bytes(unsigned char*, unsigned char*):                       # @add2bytes(unsigned char*, unsigned char*)
        mov     al, byte ptr [rsi]
        add     al, byte ptr [rdi]
        movzx   eax, al
        ret
```

It uses `mov` where `movzx` seems more reasonable, and then zero extends `al` to `eax`, but wouldn't it be much better to do `movzx` at the start?

I have 2 more examples here: https://godbolt.org/z/z45xr4hq1
GCC generates both sensible and strange `movzx`, and Clang's use of `mov r8 m` and `movzx` just makes no sense to me. I also tried adding `-march=skylake` to make sure this isn't a feature for really old architectures, but the generated assembly looks more or less the same.

The closest post I have found is https://stackoverflow.com/a/64915219/14730360 where they showed similar `movzx` uses that seem useless and/or out of place.

Do the compilers really use `movzx` poorly here, or am I missing something?

Edit: I have opened bug reports for Clang and GCC:

https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56498

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=106277

Temporary workarounds using inline assembly:
https://godbolt.org/z/7qob8G3j7

```
#define addb(a, b) asm (\
    "addb %1, %b0"\
    : "+r"(a) : "mi"(b))

int add2bytes(uint8_t* a, uint8_t* b) {
    int ret = *a;
    addb(ret, *b);
    return ret;
}
```

Now Clang -O3 produces:

```
add2bytes(unsigned char*, unsigned char*):                       # @add2bytes(unsigned char*, unsigned char*)
        movzx   eax, byte ptr [rdi]
        add     al, byte ptr [rsi]
        ret
```

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491737/compiler-generates-costly-movzx-instruction

Comment: What do you call "to break dependency" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust https://stackoverflow.com/a/43910889/14730360 has an example of how movzx breaks dependency and helps OoO execution. However, I don't think movzx does that here

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Modern x86 CPu's have many more registers than they have register _names_. That's why the physical registers are constantly being _renamed_.  This is a complicated process. One important concern is that it should be invisible to code. This matters when using partial register names like `al`. That _should_ preserve the top bits, stopping a rename. But `movzx` does a zero-extend, so it allows a rename.

Comment: Updated my answer with a section about your Godbolt link `a[a[i] | a[j]]` showing clang expecting the caller to have already extended `i` and `j` to 32-bit.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Both compilers are doing a poor job here, but clang's code is especially bad and has no real upside anywhere.  And an easily avoidable downside on everything except Intel CPUs a decade old (which rename low-8 partial registers).

The optimal asm is what you suggest, `movzx` load, then byte add, leaving a `uint8_t` result in the low byte, correctly zero-extended to `int` as required by the C semantics.  (**Thanks for reporting it upstream: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56498** - I commented there about `movzx` being a good idea for byte loads in general, even when LLVM doesn't need the result zero-extended.)

---

A `movzx` is necessary *somewhere*, but it can be in the initial load.  (A `movzx` is generally a good idea for a byte load anyway, to avoid a false dependency on the old RAX; clang's choice to save 1 byte is probably not a good one even when it doesn't end up needing a separate `movzx` right after.)

There are [basically three relevant behaviours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) here, among x86-64 CPUs.

- **Core 2 / Nehalem** (the 64-bit capable members of the P6 family): AL renamed separately from RAX if you write AL.  A later read of EAX will stall the front-end for about 3 cycles while inserting a merge uop.  Less bad than earlier P6-family, but still a significant penalty to avoid.  But these CPUs are pretty obsolete, and not something GCC's `-mtune=generic` should put much weight on for the latest GCC.  (Especially given that current nightly GCC's behaviour now won't be get baked into widely used binary packages for another year or more probably, by most stable-release distros.)

  Returning an `int` when the last instruction wrote `al` will likely lead to a penalty when the caller reads EAX.  But `mov al, [rdi]` can run without any false dependency or merging cost.
- **Sandybridge** and maybe Ivy Bridge: AL still renamed separately, but a merging uop can be inserted without any stalling, in a cycle with other uops.

  `mov al, [rdi]` still has no false dep or merging uop.  But a later read of EAX that triggers a merging uop (to merge the `add al` result with the high bytes of RAX from `movzx eax, [rdi]`) will get inserted just as cheaply as if we'd put a `movzx eax, al` in the machine code.  (If the upper bytes of RAX are all zero, merge or extend are equivalent.)
- **Haswell and later** (and maybe IvB), and **all other x86 vendors**, and low-power CPUs from Intel like Silvermont-family: no partial register renaming at all.  (Except for AH/BH/CH/DH on Intel SnB-family).  The last CPU *not* in this category is nearly a decade old, and the last CPU with major penalties (P6-family) is over a decade old.

  `mov al, [rdi]` sucks: false dependency and costs an ALU uop in the back-end to merge.  So it's extra load latency in the critical path through whatever stored the memory operand.

  Reading EAX after writing AL has zero penalty; that's not a special case at all; the merging happened when you wrote AL.

---

GCC's code is a sensible tradeoff between Core2 / Nehalem vs. modern CPUs: load with `movzx` to avoid a false dep writing a partial reg.  And a final `movzx` to avoid a partial-register stall in the caller.

But if it's going to do that, it could hurt modern Intel less by picking EDX or ECX as the temporary, since Intel can do [zero-latency `mov`-elimination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all/44193770#44193770) on `movzx r32, r8`, but not within the same register.  It still costs a front-end uop so it's not free for throughput, only latency and back-end ports.  This is a persistent missed-optimization; I don't think GCC or clang know to look for that; they commonly zero-extend 32->64 with `mov esi,esi` on a function arg, for example.

```
   movzx  edx, byte ptr [rdi]
   add     dl, [rsi]
   movzx  eax, dl             # mov-elimination possible on IvB and later (except Ice Lake with updated microcode which breaks mov-elim).
```

If optimizing specifically for Core2 / Nehalem, you'd do this:

```
   xor   eax, eax      # off the critical path, avoids partial-reg stalls for later reads of EAX after writing AL
   mov    al, [rdi]
   add    al, [rsi]
```

That's not bad on later CPUs, although the `mov al, [rdi]` would still be a micro-fuse load+ALU uop so it has extra load latency, and takes an extra slot in the scheduler and a cycle on a back-end execution port.  So 3 back-end uops, up from 2 in IvB and later with eliminated `movzx` if you pick different registers.

GCC's choice to use `movzx` because of Core2/Nehalem is highly conservative at this point; probably `-mtune=generic` in GCC12 shouldn't care about P6-family partial-register stalls since those CPUs are well over a decade old.  Especially in 64-bit code where the worst case is Core2/Nehalem, not the even longer stalls with no merging uop on earlier P6-family.  (And 64-bit code is more likely to be run on newer CPUs; one of the use-cases for `-m32` is to make code for old 32-bit-only CPUs.)

It might well be an intentional tuning choice that needs updating.  It's definitely a missed optimization with `-march` / `-mtune=` `k8` through `znver3`, or `silvermont`-family, or `sandybridge` or newer.

(Also note that some choices which *should* differ based on `-mtune` setting actually don't. GCC just has one way it always does some things, and adding hooks to make it differ based on a tuning flag hasn't been done.  Clang is the same way.  e.g. `-mtune=core2` still doesn't know to avoid partial-register stalls!)

---

**Clang** normally lives dangerously writing partial registers and otherwise ignoring false dependencies when they're not visibly loop-carried within a single function (which [can bite it in the ass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60688348/why-does-adding-an-xorps-instruction-make-this-function-using-cvtsi2ss-and-addss)).  This can save a whole instruction when it skips xor-zeroing, but saving just 1 byte doesn't seem worth it in general.  It's a false dependency and means the mov load decodes to load + ALU merge uops (to merge a new low byte into the existing 64-bit register).

Looks like clang just did its usual thing of loading 8-bit values into 8-bit registers ignoring `movzx`, then realized at the end it needed to zero-extend the result.

An optimization pass looking for a chance to fold zero-extension (after narrow math) into an earlier load would be useful.  And/or otherwise look for ways to prove that values are already zero-extended, if it doesn't do that.

Probably in general better to start doing narrow loads with `movzx` so that's more normally the case.

---

**You might want to report a missed-optimization bug, especially for clang.** Their code-gen is already a huge middle finger toward P6-family most of the time with partial-register usage, so they'd probably be interested in trying to generate the 2-instruction version. https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues

Also https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc (use the keyword missed-optimization for GCC bugs. Feel free to link this stack overflow post, and/or quote any of my comments if you want, as well as a Godbolt link.  GCC devs prefer AT&T syntax for x86 discussion / bugs.)

See also:

- [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers)
- [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to)
- https://agner.org/optimize/ (especially his microarch guide re: partial-register details for P6-family CPUs.  Last I looked, the guide incorrectly said Haswell doesn't have zero-latency `movzx eax, dl`, and that AH-merging was free; see my Q&A about HSW/SKL.  But Agner's guide is accurate AFAIK for earlier CPUs.)
- https://uops.info/ (front-end vs. back-end vs. latency costs for different instructions)
- [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) - including the part about avoiding partial-register stalls on P6, how `xor eax,eax` sets some kind of internal EAX=AL flag.

---

> I have 2 more examples here: https://godbolt.org/z/z45xr4hq1 GCC generates both sensible and strange movzx, and Clang's use of mov and movzx just makes no sense to me.

clang's `mov  ecx, edx` zero-extension from 32 to 64 instead of from 8 to 64 is because it depends on an unofficial extension to the x86-64 SysV calling convention, that [narrow args are extended to 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for/36760539#36760539).  AMD Zen CPUs can do mov-elimination on `mov ecx, edx` but not for `movzx`-byte, so this is actually more efficient, as well as saving code-size.

(GCC and clang both make callers that respect this unofficial calling-convention feature, but only clang makes callees that depend on it.  ICC doesn't do either so is not ABI-compatible with clang.)

Extension to `intptr_t` is of course necessary for all narrower args if you're going to index an array with one.  (In abstract C terms, this is just part of using the value for pointer math).  High garbage is allowed in at least the high 32 bits of the 64-bit register.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I am writing up reports for Clang and GCC, and I will be linking this post.

Comment: @PeterCordes what do you mean by "`mov al, [rdi]` would still be a micro-fuse load+ALU uop so it has extra load latency". Does microfused ALU have higher latency than explicit load + ALU?

Comment: @Noah "`mov al, [rdi]` sucks. false dependency and costs an ALU uop in the back-end to merge." It costs an extra ALU uop compared to movzx, even when dependency on old RAX value has been cleared

Comment: @Noah: No, but `movzx eax, byte ptr [rdi]` has no ALU uop at all, EAX is ready straight out of the load port, with no ALU uop as part of the dep chain.

Comment: I figured clang was assuming something like that, good to know that it has benefits. What I meant originally though, is that I don't understand why clang uses `mov r8 m` and then useless/avoidable movzx.

Comment: @Hintro: Yeah, that's just bad code, except for P6-family where you want to end with a `movzx` or start with an `xor`-zero to avoid penalties for the reader of the EAX retval.  Like I said in my answer, I assume clang gets there by doing its normal thing of a byte load without `movzx`, and then has a value that needs zero-extension so it does that.  Without considering other possibilities.  Compilers aren't AIs, they can only use strategies that humans have told them to look for, more or less.

Comment: @Hintro:  To keep compile times fast, they mostly limit themselves to O(n^2) algorithms at worst, not considering every possible sequence to find one that produces the desired results with minimal cost.  That's what a "[superoptimizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superoptimization)" does, and is effective for sequences of maybe 4 instructions or less.  But only if you have an appropriate cost-model, in this case one that takes into account partial-register effects.

Comment: @PeterCordes I think you are right about how clang generated that sequence, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/56498#issuecomment-1182582020

Comment: @PeterCordes I do have another question about the GCC code for add2bytes: would `add   al, BYTE PTR [rdi]` have to wait on the preceding `movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rsi]`? I'm thinking probably the load uop can happen independently, and then the add would happen when the load and RAX are ready?

Comment: @Hintro: That's correct, micro-fusion is only in the front-end and ROB.  In the back-end scheduler, the load and add are two separate uops, and the load can start as soon as `rsi` is ready.  And the ALU `add` can start once both its inputs are ready.

Comment: I'm currently using inline assembly workarounds for my code, so I also posted similar ones for the examples. For the `foo` example I changed the inputs to more proper types too.

Answer (score 8):

The clang bit actually seems reasonable. You get a [partial register stall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) if you write to `al` and then read from `eax`. Using `movzx` breaks this partial register stall.

The initial mov to `al` has no dependencies on existing values of `eax` (due to register renaming), so the dependencies are just the unavoidable dependencies (wait for [rsi], wait for [rdi], wait for add to complete before zero-extending).

In other words, the top 24 bits must be zeroed and the lower 8 bits must be calculated, but the two actions can be done in either order. clang just chooses to add first, zero later.

[EDIT]
As for GCC, it seems a particularly bad choice. If it had chosen `bl` as the temporary register, that last `movzx` would be zero-latency on Haswell/SkyLake, but [move elimination does not work on al to eax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169342/can-x86s-mov-really-be-free-why-cant-i-reproduce-this-at-all/44193770#44193770).

Comment: I thought the stall isn't really happening anymore since Core 2? according 2 Agner's guides. The only ones that still might be an issue is the high 8 registers. According to https://stackoverflow.com/q/45660139/14730360 movzx eax, al is not eliminated and is in a sense penalty itself, so is it really a good idea to use it here?

Comment: @Hintro: Only Sandybridge and later really made partial-register merging cheap.  Core2 and Nehalem insert a merging uop, but only after stalling for about 3 cycles IIRC.  SnB inserts a merging uop with only the front-end cost you'd expect.  (Unless it's an AH-merging uop, then it has to issue by itself).  And HSW doesn't even rename the low8 separately from the full reg, so clang's code ([as usual](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60688348)) is living dangerously with a false dependency on the old value of RAX, just to save 1 byte of code size in the load.

Comment: A,h of course, clang doesn't care about the upper 24 bits values above `al`, but a CPU that doesn't do partial renames has to track those 24 bits until they're zeroed -  two instructions further down.

Comment: @Hintro: You're correct, the final `movzx eax, al` is a dumb choice by both compilers.  Since we need to use 8-bit operand-size to return `(int)(uint8_t)sum`, on modern CPUs it would make the most sense to `movzx eax, byte [rdi]` / `add al, [rsi]` (GCC's code without the final movzx), with `-mtune=haswell` or `k8` .. `znver3`, or if `-mtune=generic` doesn't care much about Intel P6-family.  If you do want to end with movzx for Nehalem and earlier, `bl` would be a bad choice because RBX is call-preserved.  But yeah, `movzx edx, byte [rdi]` / `add dl, [rsi]` / `movzx eax, dl` would be good.

Comment: @Hintro: You might want to report a missed-optimization bug, especially for clang.  Their code-gen is already a huge middle finger toward P6-family most of the time with partial-register usage, so they'd probably be interested in trying to generate the 2-instruction version.  https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc (use the keyword missed-optimization for GCC bugs.  Feel free to link this stack overflow post, and/or quote any of my comments if you want.)