# x86: partial register stall in cvtsi2sd in big loops but not in small loops

Tags: performance, assembly, compilation, x86

I'm testing floating point code generation of some compiler. The code in question calculates a simple sum:

```
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += 1.0 / i;
    }
```

I get two versions of this code, a simple one:

```
L017:   cvtsi2sd xmm1, eax
        add     eax, byte 1
        movsd   xmm2, qword [rel L007]
        divsd   xmm2, xmm1
        addsd   xmm0, xmm2
        cmp     edx, eax 
        jge     short L017
```

and one with the loop unrolled:

```
L017:   cvtsi2sd xmm1, ecx
        movsd   xmm2, qword [rel L008]
        divsd   xmm2, xmm1
        addsd   xmm2, xmm0
        lea     edx, [rcx+1H]
        add     ecx, byte 2
        cvtsi2sd xmm0, edx
        movsd   xmm1, qword [rel L008]
        divsd   xmm1, xmm0
        addsd   xmm2, xmm1
        movapd  xmm0, xmm2
        cmp     eax, ecx
        jnz     short L017
```

The unrolled one runs much longer then the simple one: 4s vs 1.6 s when n=1000000000.
The problem is resolved by clearing the register before `cvtsi2sd` :

```
L017:   pxor xmm1, xmm1
        cvtsi2sd xmm1, ecx
        movsd   xmm2, qword [rel L008]
...
```

The new unrolled version runs as fast as the simple one. OK, this is a partial register stall, although I'd never expected it to be so bad. There are however two questions:

1. Why does it not affect the simple version? It looks like tight loops do not suffer from this stall.
2. What makes `cvtsi2sd` so much different from other scalar FP instructions, such as `addsd`? They also affect only part of an `xmm` register (in non-VEX mode, and this is the mode used).

I observed this on three processors:

- i7-6820HQ (Skylake)
- i7-8665U (Whiskey Lake)
- Xeon Gold 5120 (Skylake)

Comment: Wow, that "unrolled" version is *incredibly* pathological. I don't think a compiler wrote that? Basically, you have 2 long-latency operations: `cvtsi2sd` and `divsd`. In the first version, due to the dependency chain (only `xmm0` and `eax` feeding into `xmm0`, and `eax` is modified in every loop iteration too), `divsd` of one iteration and `cvtsi2sd` of the next iteration can execute in parallel. In the "unrolled" code, your dependencies are just all over the place, and that prevents meaningful instruction level parallelism.

Comment: "partial register *stall*" has a specific meaning (described in [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573502) for Intel P6-family), and this isn't it.  This is a *false dependency* caused by `cvtsi2sd` only writing a partial register; Intel's short-sighted design for SSE to make it faster on Pentium-III.

Comment: What makes `cvtsi2sd` different from other scalar FP operations is that it had the *chance* to be write-only, but Intel didn't take it, instead giving it a false dependency.  `addsd` already reads its destination so it's a true dependency.  Seems like a duplicate of [Why does adding an xorps instruction make this function using cvtsi2ss and addss ~5x faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60688348)