# What type of analysis do compilers do to spot opportunities for reducing entires chunks of code with calls to builtins?

Tags: c++, assembly, clang, bit-manipulation, compiler-optimization

I'm not even sure I've phrased the question using the appropriate terminology, but below is what I mean (and [here](https://godbolt.org/z/TEf1badEe) is the complete example on Compiler Explorer).

Take this code, which computes the number of set bits in the input `int`:

```cpp
int foo(int a) {
    int count = 0;
    while (a) {
        ++count;
        a &= a - 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Clang, when targeting Haswell architecture, can compile it down to just one call to `popcntl` ([even though some versions are adding a redundant instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76990878/5825294)):

```cpp
foo(int):                                # @foo(int)
        popcntl %edi, %eax
        retq
```

But why can't it do the same with the "dumber" version of it below?¹

```cpp
int foo(int a) {
    int count = 0;
    while (a) {
        count += 1 & a;
        a >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This compiles to

```
foo(int):                                # @foo(int)
        xor     eax, eax
        test    edi, edi
        je      .LBB0_2
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     ecx, edi
        and     ecx, 1
        add     eax, ecx
        sar     edi
        jne     .LBB0_1
.LBB0_2:
        ret
```

which maps very fairly well to the C++ snippet.

I would claim that the latter code (both C++ and its corresponding assembly) is closer to the human approach.

Still the same compiler, with the same options, doesn't see it's doing the same thing.

Why is that?

- Is the compiler just applying a sort of pattern matching on the source code against a map of know idioms?

  This approach would mean that the compiler is just re-applying the human approach of reading the code and concluding what it is doing, so it just goes to the list of builtins it has and picks up the one that does the same thing; so if doesn't succeed in the second snippet, it just means that who wrote the compiler took into account the first snippet and not the second one (rightfully so!).
- Or maybe the is just applying successive simplifications/realaborations to the snippet of code that happen to end up in the best scenario for the former snippet of code but not for the latter?

  If that's the case, then what is the crux of the difference between the two snippets that allows a happy ending or not?

---

¹ The only way I've test the code does the same is by verifying that the following `main` returns 0:

```cpp
int main() {
    for (auto i = 0; i != 100000; ++i) {
        if (foo(i) != bar(i)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's plain and simple pattern-matching, often using certain pre-programmed patterns. On a lower assembly level it's called peephole optimization.

Comment: One potential reason is the second function you showed does not do the same thing as the first. https://godbolt.org/z/dP9EW8Wfs

Comment: Godbolt also has a GUI to peek into LLVMs optimization steps and see how they transformed the code. In your case, it looks to me as if the `LoopDeletionPass` figured out the semantics of the loop and replaced it with a popcount instruction: https://godbolt.org/z/vs1s763bT. Unsuccessful transformation for comparison: https://godbolt.org/z/osabMqx75.

Comment: "The only way I've tested..." when I run this test, it fails https://godbolt.org/z/5zbzWveWj

Comment: Every one of the few C++ compilers in common use has it's own individual development history that evolved over the course of multiple decades. There is no stock set of algorithms that every C++ compiler follows, somehow. Each compiler uses its own distinct optimization algorithms.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, yeah I did test it, then I managed to copy the wrong version over here :D I should have put the test in the CE example in the first place :P

Comment: in the meantime an answer has been posted that refers to the original version of the question...It also refers to the corrected version of the code, hence I'd suggest to roll back the edit

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, what would the advantage be for the next reader? Whatever it is, I think they can gather it from these comments.

Comment: comments are shortlived, dont have an edit history, and can vanish at any time. The advantage would be that the answer would be consistent with the question rather than talking about code that isnt present in the question. Nevermind, the answer has already been fixed.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/91j3feoE9) is some collection of popcnt patterns, only two of which are recognized as such (one of them without redundant cmov)

Comment: Not directly related, but in both versions here, the argument `a` needs to be declared as `unsigned`.  As it stands, when given a negative input, the first version would cause UB by eventually evaluating `INT_MIN - 1`, and the second version would loop infinitely (and eventually overflow `count`).  This doesn't end up affecting how they are optimized, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point at which LLVM simplifies your first function is a `LoopDeletionPass` (see https://godbolt.org/z/z1GT7Kx9q) which turns the entire loop into:

```
%0 = call i32 @llvm.ctpop.i32(i32 %a)
```

You can see that this optimization pass is only performed after many others have been applied.
Usually, optimization enables other optimizations, and in turn, those enable other optimizations.
This is repeated until a fixed limit of passes is reached.

After further optimization passes, you are left with the IR:

```
define dso_local noundef i32 @foo(int)(i32 noundef %a) local_unnamed_addr {
entry:
  %0 = icmp eq i32 %a, 0
  %1 = tail call i32 @llvm.ctpop.i32(i32 %a)
  %spec.select = select i1 %0, i32 0, i32 %1
  ret i32 %spec.select
}
```

Essentially, the compiler recognizes certain patterns (such as a loop that does certain things) and turns them into a set of instructions that does the same, but better (such as a call to an LLVM intrinsic function). This is called [peephole optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization).

#### How to ensure pattern recognition

Whether an optimization can be performed often boils down to whether compiler developers have bothered specifying a pattern. Which patterns can be recognized might seem arbitrary.

If you don't want to put blind faith into the compiler, use intrinsics such as [`__builtin_popcount`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) or the C++20 function [`std::popcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know of `std::popcount`, and wow for that feature of CE you showed!

Comment: @Enlico: Another example of idiom recognition in clang is [How does clang generate non-looping code for sum of squares?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74417624) (or for any power, including the simple case of `sum += i;`.)  Also the much smaller-scope case of `(x<<n) | (x>>(32-n)` or a safer version of that for `n=0` or `n=32` as a rotate, where that's truly just a peephole optimization that can be done late during generation of target machine code: [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776508)

Comment: @Enlico: GCC also recognizes the `a &= a - 1;` (clear lowest-set bit) idiom but not the `count += a&1; a>>=1;` 
 idiom.  IIRC from last time I looked (oh, it was while writing the answer I linked in my last comment), the GCC source code has a function called `number_of_iterations_popcount`.  Compilers already care a lot about figuring stuff out about loop trip counts, like whether they're guaranteed non-zero, guaranteed finite, etc. so they're already analyzing the recurrence involved in the loop bound.

Comment: So maybe that's why it was worth looking for that method (Kernighan's) but not other loops.  Or perhaps some important source code (like some SPECint benchmarks?) happened to use that implementation instead of the other.  If you're going to pick a portable looping implementation at all, that's typically better than the fully naive version that only shifts one bit at a time.